# Objects becoming not Clickable, and locking out of Pose mode?

Tags: objects, selection-tools, pose-mode

I have very Weird issues, where my objects become greyed out.

As soon as it occurs, i can not switch to the pose mode. 
I have tried removing the tick on "selectable" and adding it again.

It makes my Object selectable, but i am still locked out of Pose Mode.

Any Idea?

Comment: You can only get into Pose Mode if you have at least one armature in your scene. The armature must be selected. Do you have an armature selected when trying to enter Pose Mode?